# "line length exception" in hashcat (kali linux)

Tags: passwords, cryptography, hashing

I've received this line:

```
root:$1$25A116L54$7/IbiL1ZsUyPwYBx/zuNv/
```

and asked to crack the password. So, I created a `crack.hash` file and put the following in it:

```
$1$25A116L54$7/IbiL1ZsUyPwYBx/zuNv/
```

And then ran the following command in the terminal:

```
hashcat -m 0 -a 0 -o /crackResult.txt --remove /crack.hash /passwords.txt
```

And the result is:

```
skip line: $1$25A116L54$7/IbiL1ZsUyPwYBx/zuNv/ (line length exception)
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: try with -m 500

Comment: Also spelling mistake in their error (lenght should be length) XD

Answer (score 7):

This looks like a unix password string.

```
-m 0 is for MD5 hashes
```

Use

```
-m 500 for Unix hashes
```

See https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hashcat

Comment: Very useful tip. But doesn't solve the problem... Is that because the length of the salt which is 9 chars?

Comment: This does actually answer your question. The hashcat 'line-length exception' error is a bit unclear; what it means is that it was expecting a hash of a different length (because you've asked it to crack raw MD5 (-m 0) when you have a *MD5crypt* (-m 500) hash. Change your syntax to use -m 500, just as mbs and Jor-el said.